# "Любимый писатель" - это что?

Tags: семантика

Очень хотелось бы услышать ваше понимание самого сочетания.
Не фамилии, а именно **определение понятия**. Хотя бы на нетривиальных синонимах.

Могу с другой стороны начать. "Любимый писатель" - это идиома или семантика сочетания все-таки вытекает из значений составляющих?

*Предыстория такова. Я довольно давно задумался над тем, что имеют в виду люди, называя любимым того или иного автора. 
И чем больше думал, тем меньше понимал. Ну а сейчас вот в одном разговоре меня окончательно запутали, сведя все к мантре "если это можно объяснить, то это уже не любовь".*

*У меня есть много любимых **произведений**, вопросов нет. Это то, что лежало (в докомпьютерную эру) на столе, это то, что помнишь, знаешь, перечитываешь, получаешь удовольствие, обсуждаешь на форуме...* 
*Но я совсем не уверен, что их авторы - мои любимые писатели. Я даже в критерии совсем не уверен, что "любимый писать" - автор любимых книг.
Мне вот в пятом классе учебник по алгебре - Киселева, кажется - очень нравилось читать. На тот момент Киселев - мой любимый писатель?!*

Вопрос не стебный. Всё серьезно.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю не стоит здесь поверять алгеброй гармонию. Любовь - это всё-таки чувство, а не разум. В понятие любимый писатель каждый вкладывает своё. Любимый писатель это тот, чью книгу ты купишь и прочитаешь, только потому, что на обложке его имя, даже если тематика произведения тебя не интересует. Любимый писатель это тот, чьё творчество и биографию охота изучать независимо от его популярности в твоём круге общения.  Что может вызвать эту любовь? Схожесть мыслей, восприятия мира, способа мышления и построения фраз, эмоций в конце концов. Так что это не идиома.

Comment: Марк, алгебра здесь ни при чем. Я буду вполне удовлетворен если мне что-то внятное пояснят имеyно в терминах гармонии. Да и вы в общем-то поняли вопрос, судя по попытке ответа. Другое дело, что не до конца, видно, прониклись.. Вот возьмите, скажем, проблему перевода. Или просто общения с человеком межкоммуникативного общения. Да мало ли что. Лично у меня этот вопрос вызван к жизни полным когнитивным диссонансом от общения с двумя человеками, которые признались в любви к Достоевскому и ничего внятного не смогли сказать о сути этой самой любви.

Comment: @behemothus это очень субъективно. Почему Достоевский любим конкретным человеком может сказать только он сам. Для этого нужно проанализировать свои вкусы,  увлечения и пр. А делать так захочет не каждый, потому и не знают причины своей любви.

Comment: Субъективны персоналии, само чувство вполне поддается вполне объективной трактовке. Иначе бы и само понятие не могло существовать. (+) Можно же проще спросить, "а ты уверен, что это именно любовь? на каком основании?". Может это не любовь, а приступ бронхиальной астмы?

Comment: Мне нравится ответ Марка Из. Он также проясняет, почему автор любимой книги != любимый автор. Ну, точнее, не не равно, а не обязательно равно. 
А про то, что Ваши знакомые не могли объяснить, почему Достоевского любят - так может, они не умеют мысли формулировать? Или Вы с ними совершенно разными категориями мыслите?:-)

Answer (score 1):

Писатель может стать любимым. Его не трудно читать, он не стоит на месте и не повторяется, согласно писательскому ремеслу, стабилен по уровню мастерства, совпал с и верен необходимой (читающему) тематике, и тексты его не требуют работы со словарём. Любовь эта порождает желание поделиться с ближним, но чем «ближе» писатель, тем менее вероятна перспектива его обсуждения, ибо это чревато не виртуальными травмами. Это — показатель градуса.

Comment: Это вообще не по теме. Я же не прошу вас сочинение на вольную тему написать. Определение дайте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Пардон, если вы полашаете, что *Его не трудно читать, он не стоит на месте и не повторяется, согласно писательскому ремеслу, стабилен по уровню мастерства, совпал с и верен необходимой (читающему) тематике, и тексты его не требуют работы со словарём* - это критерий любви к писателю, то это, конечно ответ какой-никакой. Но сомнительно, чтобы это было правой. Это не любовь, а какое-то   техзадание на творчество.

Comment: Я дал предположительную базу, конечно, говоря о своём опыте и о себе, не имеющем на сей день любимого писателя, которая, если бы срослось, помогла бы заполнить брешь: иметь любимого писателя полезно и нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Любимый писатель--творческая личность, способная вербально,через свои произведения выразить эмоции, чувства, мысли,позицию,которые лично Вы разделяете,иногда не отдавая себе в том отчета. Проще говоря,« и я бы так написал»,«подписываюсь под каждым словом», да таланта (может быть) не хватает.

Comment: Во, вот это уже вариант. Спасибо. А скажите, как вы думаете, это ваше субъективно-личное "определение" или годится для любого человека? Может ли для кого-то автор, пишущий совсем не то, под чем этот другой подписался бы, оказаться любимым? Или вообще, автор пишущий плохо? Я веду к тому, верно ли, что *"любимый писатель" = "автор любимых книг"?*

Comment: Любимый писатель-- автор любимых книг, это, логично, не так ли? Каким образом Вы с ним знакомитесь? Через произведения. Первые вопросы психологического характера. Не может. Каждый человек соизмеряет все со своими представлениями о мире. Хорошо то, что мне нравится. Поэтому оно и любимо.

Comment: *Любимый писатель-- автор любимых книг, это, логично, не так ли?* Для меня лично - нет, конечно. Иначе бы и не спрашивал. Вот например, есть у меня любимая книга "Приключения капитана Врунгеля". Ничего более её автор (А. Некрасов) известного не написал. Некрасов - мой любимый писатель? Что-то я сомневаюсь... То же самое - с Ильфом-Петровым. Леонидом Соловьевым  (автором "Повести о Ходже Насреддине"), Сервантесом. Но это только частный случай, причина-то глубже... И вот сформулировать эту причину я не могу пока.

Comment: Но это ладно. Я очень сомневаюсь, что все определят для себя любимого писателя именно так. Не помню кто, кто-то из довольно известных в литературном мире критиков, как-то сказал, что его любимое чтение - Гете и бульварные романы. Первый - выше всякой критики, вторые - ниже. Поэтому читая их, он чувствует себя вполне комфортно. Вот вам и "любимый писатель" ))))

Comment: Неосознанность только подтверждает вышесказанное. И качество произведения не идет вразрез с понятием "любимый". Любят не за что‐то.

Comment: Я говорю об осознанности и неосознанности. Я говорю о том, что субъективно считаю ваш критерий (осознанный или нет) неприменимым для многих, если не для большинства. Неосознанно - это "любовь зла, полюбишь и козла". Хотя и в ьаком раскладе можно найти рациональное объяснение. Но я совсем не об этом сейчас.

Answer (score 0):

В моём понимании "любимый писатель" - сравнительная категория, он как бы трудами своими субъективно "лучше прочих", чем-то ближе их, его книги (не одно только полюбившееся произведение - оценка возникает "по совокупности") предпочтут, если речь зайдёт о выборе, что взять с собой на Марс и т. п. Бывает, конечно, и "один из любимых". Попытки дать определение любви давались некоторыми известными людьми - не все люди отрицают познаваемость явлений ради умиления от сознания непостижимости чего-либо. Ахмадуллина определяла это для себя так: "он хороший, он лучше меня" - здесь тоже заложено сравнение, разве что любимых писателей не с собой сопоставляют, а с их коллегами. Что касается авторов книг специальных жанров, то в рамках специализации может найтись "любимый автор" учебников по алгебре или китайских самоучителей; в каждой интересующей области может найтись свой "любимый". Со следующим трудом такого "любимого автора" обязательно ознакомятся и его предпочтут, если встанет вопрос о выборе.

Comment: А чем-он лучше-то, чем ближе? И вообще, это точно о писателе? Вы ничего о том не сказали. Замените слово "писатель" на "водитель троллебуса" - у вас ничего по сути не изменится.

Comment: Про определение любви - это не ко мне. То, что отдельные авторы выдают за "определение" - это словоблудие. Любовь - это эиоциональное чувство, которое может наполняться отчасти различным содержанием. Вполне достаточное для первого раза определение. Греки вот не побоялись придумать девять "муз", за разные чувства отвечающие. Но это все равно не по теме. меня интересуют понятие "любимый писатель", а не любовь как таковая. Ваше чувство к писателю эмоционально? Или вы даже этого не можете сказать?